# Floppy Disk to ??? Controller

Tags: usb, sata, pci, floppy, disk-controller

I have a motherboard which has:

1. SATA
2. IDE
3. Internal USB headers

I need to attach a floppy disk drive, but there is no onboard floppy disk controller. I've looked for the following:

1. Internal USB Floppy Drive
2. Internal Floppy to USB Cable
3. Internal Floppy to SATA Cable
4. PCI Floppy Disk Controller

I can't find anything suitable apart from external USB floppy disk drives, but I'd really rather it be internal.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the interface of the Floppy Disk Drive look like? Is it something like [this](http://it4nextgen.com/floppy-drive.html)? Old internal drives [require an onboard controller](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/275198-28-internal-floppy-drive) so you may need to get an external one.

Comment: @MC10 Yes it's a 34 pin header. I already have an external one; that's my fallback if I can't get one to work internally. The external one is just a standard USB drive, so the other thing I was wondering was could I get an external one and get a usb port to pin out cable and "bodge" it

Comment: Yeah, I tried searching for a 34-pin adapter but I don't think they exist. I guess it requires the onboard controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no internal PC (PCIe, etc.) floppy controllers being manufactured anymore, and I don't believe there was *ever* a PCIe one.

Get an external USB floppy drive and either live with it outside your chassis, or hack it apart an mount it internally.

Here's a YouTube video of a guy hacking a 3.5" internal Floppy/Card reader drive and combining it with a USB external floppy drive to create a working internal USB floppy drive: [Making an Internal USB Floppy Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91MblZpho1A)

Comment: :( It's for a project PC I'm building. Found a motherboard with LGA775 CPU socket, DDR3 RAM and....ISA slots (can you believe it...I can resurrect my old Sound Blaster 16 again)...I just need a Floppy Disk Drive for the DOS stuff. Maybe I'll hunt around for an ISA floppy controller.